# Elimination theory by algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f_0,...,f_n $ be n+1 homogeneous polynomials of fixed degrees $d_0,...,d_n > 0$ in n+1 variables $x_0, . . . , x_n$. I want to prove that there exists an expression D, polynomial in the coefficients of $f_i$’s, such that D = 0 if and only if the system of equations $f_0 = · · · = f_n$ = 0 has non-trivial solutions. So the classical special case is when $d_0 =···=d_n =1$, D is the determinant.

I asked the question before, but now I realize that this can be done by using the knowledge of algebraic geometry. If I can prove the set of coefficients which make the system of equations have non-trivial solutions is closed and has c0dimension 1, then I am done since in this case the set must be zero set of a single polynomial. So how should I do this dimension counting?

Comment: This is Macaulay's resultant in $n+1$ indeterminates.

Comment: @Bernard Yes! But  can I prove this without formula, just by dimension counting?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a trivial problem…

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a condition for a group of homogeneous polynomials have common non-zero roots.
We can do this for each pair.
for g, f, define their **resultant**,
the details are given by this notes:
http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/2WF02/resultant.pdf

Comment: You are definitely right. But what I am looking for is to prove this by dimension counting, do you have idea about that?